# Install/import SSL certificate on Windows Server 2003/IIS 6.0

Tags: ssl, iis-6, ssl-certificate

A couple of months ago we ordered an SSL certificate for a client's server using the request guide in IIS 6.0. This worked fine and the guide was completed when we received the certificate.

But about 2 weeks ago the server crashed and had to be restored. Now I can't seem to get the site running. I have the .cer file, but what is the correct procedure to import the the certificate?

I hope some of you can help me..

-- Christian

Answer (score 2):

The .cer file won't work except on the same machine that created the original CSR.  Your best bet is to get your certificate authority to allow you to create another certificate because of your server rebuild.

Next time what you can do is after you complete the process and have the certificate working, you can export the certificate including private key and save it in a safe place.  That can in turn be imported onto other machines in the event of a server crash or reinstall.